# Is there a way in which I can compare product id with the order id to display content on front end before placing the order?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm developing a plugin using woocommerce which will display some content to the user on the basis of the product he selects. He will be able to perform customization before checking out and the customization templates will be displayed on the basis of product selected.